# Slide down and up function problem with flex: 1

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, flexbox, slidedown

```js
$(".div3Btn").click(function() {
  $(".div2").show("slide", {
    direction: "up"
  }, 5000);
});
```

```css
.div1 {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: #919191;
}

.div2 {
  display: flex;
  overflow-y: auto;
  flex: 1;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: #a8d810;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="div1">
  <div class="div2" style="display: none;">hjghjgjghj</div>
  <div class="div3">
    <button class="div3Btn">Click me!</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have a question about using the `show()`/`hide()` function with time and direction. As the above snippet shows, if the button was clicked, it will immediately jump to the bottom, but not following the div1 to slide down. Then how can I fix it if I want to use that function?

```js
$(".div3Btn").click(function() {
  $(".div2").slideToggle(5000);
});
```

```css
.div1 {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: #919191;
}

.div2 {
  display: flex;
  overflow-y: auto;
  flex: 1;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: #a8d810;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="div1">
  <div class="div2" style="display: none;">hjghjgjghj</div>
  <div class="div3">
    <button class="div3Btn">Click me!</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

(The problem is quite similar to using Firefox to run the link function)

Another question about slide down and up is when I use `flex: 1` for some divs, and then use the `slideToggle()` function, it does not have any slide down or up animation of the div. How to fix it if I must use `flex: 1` for divs?

Comment: Hey! I edited your question. JSFiddle links are *okay*, but formatting the code as a snippet is *better*. You can find an intro about snippet in [this Stack Overflow blog post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Answer (score 0):

I think you've formatted the `.show()` function wrong. Try `.show( duration [, easing ] [, complete ] )`

```js
$(".div3Btn").click(function() {
  $(".div2").show(5000, "swing", function() {
    // Animation complete.
  });
});
```

```css
.div1 {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: #919191;
}

.div2 {
  display: flex;
  overflow-y: auto;
  flex: 1;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: #a8d810;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="div1">
  <div id="div2" class="div2" style="display: none;">hjghjgjghj</div>
  <div class="div3">
    <button id="div3Btn" class="div3Btn">Click me!</button>
  </div>
</div>
```